# Returning a value from the jar file to the calling batch file

Tags: java, batch-file, jar

I am calling a jar file from a bat file. I have three scenario which I need to handle in the batch file depending on how the computation in jar file completes. In the success and the failure cases, I am relying on the ERRORLEVEL variable in teh batch file. But there is a third case which I need to handle in the batch file. To address this I have updated the Java source code as shown below:

```
if( !listJMXDomains.userHadSession())
{
    System.out.print("NoiX active sessions found for the given user " + user_name );
    System.exit(404);
}
```

When I run this on eclipse debugger, I see that the program terminated with exit value of 404. But when I use the ERRORLEVEL variable in the batch file, I am not able to capture the return value of 404. It is always a 0. The following is what I have on the batch file:

```
CALL java -classpath %CLASSPATH% -Xmx128m com.esml.listjmxdomains.ESML_listJMXDomains %USER_NAME% esmltcdev PoolA
echo %errorlevel%
```

I have tried including the 'CALL', removing it etc, still the same problem persists.

Please let me know what I could be missing....

Thanks,
Pavan.

Comment: 404 might not be a valid return code.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/418784/what-is-the-min-and-max-values-of-exit-codes-in-linux.  Try using 4 instead of 404.  And of course, verify that your program is printing that message.

Comment: What is the Java program. Type `where java` to see what it finds.

Comment: It is the java.exe Mark and Mofi.

Comment: Lose the `call` part. See `call /?`. Does the text print. Your code only has one path programed. Also print out %user_name% to see if it exists and there are no special characters in it.

Comment: I updated my command to include full path to java.exe to rule out anything. Still it did not resolve the problem. I also removed the CALL part.

Comment: @VGR I updated the code to return 4, instead of 404. No luck.